# Load fixture.json through python script

Tags: python, django

I have fixture JSON file for Django models and I want to update data through a python script. I don't want to run command on terminal `python manage.py loaddata fixture.json`. This I want to do through python script.

I have created virtual environment for Django. I also want to start virtual environment through script. I wrote small script but it is not working.

```
from subprocess import call
from os import chdir, getcwd

original_directory = getcwd()
chdir('/home/naresh/test_django')
call('source bin/activate', shell = True)
chdir('graphossss/')
call('python manage.py loaddata background/fixtures.json', shell= True)
chdir(original_directory)
```

Got error:

> "File "manage.py", line 8, in
>
> from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>
> ImportError: No module named django.core.management"

This means virtual env is not activated...

Comment: You're still getting the syntax wrong on subprocess.call. Please look closely at my answer.

Comment: @MorganThrapp i tried with ur code but with ur code "call('source', 'bin/activate')" is also giving error but with abobe code it is not giving error..

Comment: can't you just add your virutalenv path to your python path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by calling call_command method

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('loaddata', 'data.json', stdout=out, verbosity=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Subprocess.call` uses each option to the command line as a seperate argument.

For example:

```
from subprocess import call
from os import chdir, getcwd

original_directory = getcwd()
chdir('/home/naresh/test_django')
call('source', 'bin/activate')
call('python', 'manage.py', 'loaddata', 'fixtures.json')
chdir(original_directory)
```

Comment: @Naresh You have to give more information than just "not working".

Comment: i got error "from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management" which means virtual env is not activated.....

Comment: @Naresh Edit the error in to your main post. It won't format correctly in a comment.

Comment: Is it code in your main post exactly what you're running?